# Regex for fetch the CSRF token value from the response body

Tags: jmeter

In my sample response of Jmeter contain a CSRF token, how to extract it using regular expression extractor ?

```
app.load( {"system":true,"redirect":false,"name":"login\/js\/index","url":"login","container":"#pyModule","scope":null,"infinite":false,"action":{"method":"update","target":"container"},"csrf":{"name":"csrf_token","value":"10ff930c4ec316d4cf203f1e6efb72e8"},
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
{"name":"csrf_token","value":"(\w+)"}
```

should do the trick for you

[image]

In the above expression:

- `\w` is the [metacharacter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html#meta_chars) standing for "word" (alphanumeric, including underscores)
- `+` is for repetition (don't stop after first match)

If you have problems with coming up with a proper regular expression you may find [Boundary Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor) easier to use, you just need to provide "left" and "right" boundaries and it will extract everything in-between:

[image]

Moreover it works faster and consumes less resources than the Regular Expression Extractor. More information: [The Boundary Extractor vs. the Regular Expression Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-boundary-extractor-vs-the-regular-expression-extractor-in-jmeter)

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try below,

1. Add a regular expression extractor to your http request
2. Name : CSRF_Token
3. Regex : "name":"csrf_token",(?:"value":")(.*?)(?:")
4. Template : $1$
5. Match Number : 0
6. Default Value : NOT_FOUND